# Getting ModuleNotFoundError in python, package exists in virtual environment though

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-3.6, intellisense

I am new to python and writing my first python file using Visual Studio Code. Till yesterday the code was working fine. But today it is starting to give ModuleNotFoundError. I double-checked the package and the package is there under lib folder of the virtual environment. Moreover, IntelliSense is also working fine, whenever I write import it shows the requests module in the available list. I am facing problems with IntelliSense also, as sometimes it stops working for no reason.

The major change that I did before executing the code is the integration of GitLab with my project.

```
Python Version: 3.6.2
Operating System: Windows
Git Version: 2.23.0
Pylint Version: 2.3.1
pip Version: 19.2.2
Requests Version: 2.22.0
Pytest Version: 5.1.1
```

Enabled Extensions:

```
Npm
Npm Intellisense
Ayu
Code Runner
AYU
Markdownlint
Predawn Themekit
Python by Microsoft
```

Can anyone have gone through with the same problem? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Attachments
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Issue resolved I was running it using Ctrl+Alt+N which was creating this issue. But running the file in terminal giving me the expected result without any error. Can anyone tell me how to run this file using a code-runner shortcut? Or is there any other shortcut to run the file in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved I was running it using `Ctrl+Alt+N (code-runner shortcut to run a project)`which was creating this issue. But running the file in terminal using `Run Python File in Terminal (option in the context menu when we do right-click in source .py file)` giving me the expected result without any error.

Then I googled for how to alter this behavior so that I can get the same results by using `Ctrl+Alt+N` as well.

I found that; I need to add the following script under user's settings.json.

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "h:\\practice\\virtualenv\\Scripts\\activate.bat && python -u"
    }
```

Here is my complete user's settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Predawn",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "ayu",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "h:\\practice\\virtualenv\\Scripts\\activate.bat && python -u"
    }
}
```